# monaco editor doesen't show suggestion for printf

Tags: editor, monaco-editor, visual-studio-monaco

Here I have attached screenshot which is showing no suggestions for printf.
Please help me to solve the above issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It has been a few weeks. Have you been able to solve this issue? If so, would you mind sharing?

Comment: There is no screenshot